# UITableView within UITableViewCell with AutoDimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I want to implement a UITableview inside a UITableViewCell. Only condition is I need to use UITableViewAutomatic Dimension for both table. Giving a fix height works fine, but I have no idea how to implement with UITableViewAutomatic dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 steps

1- In `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120 // initial height to help auto-layout such as current cell height in xib  
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

2- Create your cell constrained properly from top to bottom so auto-layout can infer it's real height in run-time

Also check this [tutorial](http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-automatic-row-height/)

Comment: Cell height depend upon content size of inner tableview. I have given top,bottom,leading,trainling to zero.

Comment: The constraints should be setup in such a way that you should be able to tell the height from the verticals constraints applied. In your case you should set the `topAnchor` and `bottomAnchor` of the `tableView` to the `tableViewCell`'s contentView and specify a height using `heightAnchor`

Comment: That is the issue I use a Height constraint then I have to get the height of inner tableview in advance.